# Extracting admin boundary data from OpenStreetMap

Tags: shapefile, polygon, openstreetmap, overpass-api, extract

[image]

I'm really just looking to get borders for cities and regions around the world. Ideally in a shapefile format.

Does anyone know how I can do that from OpenStreetMap?

Comment: Using overpass queries you can extract specific elements from the openstreetnap database https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API

Comment: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/J7l (admin level 4) for New Delhi then use the export tab and save to GeoJSON this will load in QGIS and save as shapefile.

Comment: Actually, in the download data pack from Geofabrik, it doesn't include the boundary data

Comment: Are you completely sure?

Comment: There is this tool now: https://osm-boundaries.com/

Answer (score 7):

If it's for specific cities and regions, you can use [Overpass Turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/) to create queries like `admin_level=6` to find border ways. You'll want to consult the [Tag:boundary=administrative wiki page](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:boundary%3Dadministrative#10_admin_level_values_for_specific_countries) to make sure that you're using the right admin level for the country you're looking at.

If, however, you want to just extract those borders for the whole planet, you'll need to download a local copy of the OSM database from https://planet.openstreetmap.org/, then use a tool like [Osmosis](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis) to extract the particular objects you're looking for. In Osmosis, you'd need to use the `--tag-filter` command, among other things.

I don't personally have experience working with OSM data directly with GDAL, but it does have the capability of reading and filtering OSM files, which you can read about [here](https://www.gdal.org/drv_osm.html). The added benefit of GDAL is that you can also use it in conjunction with `ogr2ogr` to export directly to shapefile.

Finally, perhaps you're really just looking for shapefiles of those boundaries, and don't want to fiddle around with these commands. In that case, you have a couple options.

1. Download regions and countries individually from [Geofabrik](https://download.geofabrik.de/), which come as shapefiles. This is ill-advised, as the extracts will contain **everything**, and will require some work to filter out the boundaries and bring them all together from disparate layers. And that's not to mention that it would eat up a lot of storage space unnecessarily.
2. You can always just go to an alternate source like Natural Earth, which provides global coverage of [boundaries as shapefiles](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/), among many other things.

If, for whatever reason, the data *must* come from OSM, then I would suggest getting familiar with GDAL and/or Osmosis.

Comment: https://www.openstreetmap.org/user/SomeoneElse/diary/47007 is a worked example of solving a similar problem, and contains links to the scripts that were used.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how many boundaries you would like to extract from OSM. For single city shape osmnx would be easiest option.

If you need to get admin boundaries for whole country, processing OSM data dump for country is the only viable option.

Here is a complete example in Python how to do it

https://medium.com/p/9f108c34f86

Comment: Good articles on https://max-coding.medium.com/